# Populated association fields on find route with blueprint option ON

Tags: sails.js, waterline, model-associations, sails-permissions

My app has a "Categories" model.

Categories can be children of other categories.

So there is a "CategoriesAssociations" model.

Here is the code :

```
/* api/models/Categories.js */ 

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string"
    },
    parents: {
      collection: "categoriesassociations",
      via: "child"
    },
    children: {
      collection: "categoriesassociations",
      via: "parent"
    }
  }
}

/* api/models/CategoriesAssociations.js */ 

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    parent: {
      model: "categories"
    },
    child: {
      model: "categories"
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I use the `find` route aka `/categories` I get this :

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-08-24T14:16:46.662Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-24T14:24:23.819Z",
    "name": null,
    "id": "55db274e424996cc7e7512e2"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-08-24T14:18:29.748Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-24T14:18:41.105Z",
    "name": "test",
    "id": "55db27b5424996cc7e7512e4"
  }
]
```

So no trace of the `parents` and `children` properties.

The associations are indeed created in the database for when I request `/categories/55db27b5424996cc7e7512e4/children` I get this :

```
[
  {
    "parent": "55db27b5424996cc7e7512e4",
    "child": "55db274e424996cc7e7512e2",
    "createdAt": "2015-08-24T14:32:43.429Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-24T14:32:43.429Z",
    "id": "55db2b0bc97cc73083017f60"
  }
]
```

Sails docs states that the `populate` configuration key for blueprints defines :

> Whether the blueprint controllers should populate model fetches with data from other models which are linked by associations. If you have a lot of data in one-to-many associations, leaving this on may result in very heavy api calls.

The value is `true` in my project but still, associations attributes don't get populated.

Did I misunderstand the docs or is there a problem with my project?

I use sails 0.11.x

Comment: Is there any actual data for those properties in the models that are listed?  That is, do those two model instances have children and parents?

Comment: Yes they do. There are to categories associated via one record in the association table.

Comment: @sgress454 created the tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sails-permissions

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I'm using [sails-permissions](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions) which has overrides blueprints' `populate` config :

```
sails.config.blueprints.populate = false;
```

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/issues/129) to know why it's done globally and how to fix the problem.